# Pretty average --

Tags: mathematics, geometry

You are given a tetrahedron $T=ABCD$. Average opposing edges to create a second tetrahedron $T'=A'B'C'D'$ with $\overline{A'B'}=\overline{C'D'}=\frac 1 2[\overline{AB}+\overline{CD}]$ etc. Place $T$ and $T'$ in space; they may overlap if you like. For each of the three pairs $(\overline{AB'},\overline{A'B})$, $(\overline{AC'},\overline{D'B})$ and $(\overline{AD'},\overline{C'B})$ take its average, square it and, finally, sum the three to get $x$. Now relabel $T$ and $T'$ back-to-front, i.e. rename $A\rightarrow D, B\rightarrow C$ etc. And do the same calculation once more to get $y$. Compare $xy$ to the product $z=\overline{AA'}\,\overline{BB'}\,\overline{CC'}\,\overline{DD'}$.

Can $z$ ever be larger or at least (non-trivially) equal $xy$? If so which of the two?

(Conceived by me. Elegant---easily fit back of envelope---solution exists.)

Picture (**may be considered a spoiler if you are really strict on that**) spoileriness $\frac 1 2 / 10$: may give you ideas

> [image]
>
>
>  One possible arrangement. But note that, for example, $AC'BD'$ are not required to be in the same plane.

Maybe it's time for a first hint/spoiler **don't read if you want the full (quite satisfying even if I say so myself) experience!**
spoileriness $3/10$: cryptic but not very

> The average herring is maybe not red but a deep shade of pink.

Second hint/spoiler **don't read unless you are positively desperate**
spoileriness $5/10$: won't feel like you solved yourself

> Like someone trying to hide their mediocrity by pretending to be just an average lad/lass.

Third spoiler-not-hint **don't read**
spoileriness $7/10$: enjoy being spoon-fed?

> Not all mediocrities are equal.

Fourth wrecking-ball-not-spoiler **impervious to advice aren't you?!**
spoileriness $10/10$: might as well come down to your place and solve it for you

> Even if they hide behind a ptosh name.

... one ... last ... mega-spoiler **only read if you are one of the I-like-geometry-but-have-zero-background tribe!** How would you know? If you barely remember the sum of angles in a triangle and the name Pythagoras rings a bell but you've never heard of, say, inscribed angles or a chap called Heron then you may qualify---none of the names I just dropped have any bearing on the problem at hand, I just used them to gauge your general level of geometry. You need to know one result from elementary geometry which is a classic but not quite as famous as $a^2+b^2=c^2$ If and only if you think that's what's holding you back read the last spoiler spoileriness $20/10$

> Look up Ptolemy's inequality.

If you answer, please state whether you looked at the hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first get through the daunting task of actually writing out the expressions to be compared. Our $x$ is $$\left(\frac{AB'+BA'}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{AC'+BD'}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{AD'+BC'}{2}\right)^2.$$Now $y$ is basically this, except with a relabelling of variables, and writing out the entire product $xy$ is quite painful, so we will defer that to when we really need it.

Now we will start the estimates.

> AM-GM inequality says $\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^2\ge ab$, so $x$ is lower-bounded by $$AB'\cdot BA'+AC'\cdot BD'+AD'\cdot BC'.$$
>  [Ptolemy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_inequality) now lets us say $$x\ge AB'\cdot BA'+\boxed{AC'\cdot BD'+AD'\cdot BC'}\ge AB'\cdot A'B+\boxed{AB\cdot C'D'}.$$ This seems to resist further simplication/estimation; but thankfully, the question says $C'D'$ is equal to $A'B'$! This and another bout of Ptolemy gets us to $$x\ge AB'\cdot A'B+AB\cdot C'D'=AB'\cdot A'B+AB\cdot A'B'\ge AA'\cdot BB'.$$

Looks like we are almost done! Since $y$ was just $x$ relabelled (and the problem conditions are all stable under that relabelling), the same logic applies to it, giving

> $$y\ge  CC'\cdot DD'.$$And so $$xy\ge AA'\cdot BB'\cdot CC'\cdot DD'\ge z.$$The conclusion follows immediately.

---

### Puzzle feedback time!

Cute puzzle! There are some 'aha!' moments as to what piece of information feeds into where, and it's satisfying to finish.

I believe the main reason this sat unattempted so far is that the expressions of $x$ and $y$ are *really* scary. The problem statement describes these quantities in (a lot of) words, so any progress must begin with converting this to math expressions, and that kind of feels like a menial chore.

I'll admit I looked at all the hints, but that's primarily because I was hoping to find something that would cut down on the work involved. I thought of using the main result the later hints are cluing a while back (it's one of the very few ways of handing products of lengths I know) but felt "eh I'll wait till someone else works out the expression for $xy$". I feel the question would be better if that expression was given to begin with.

Another minor beef I have is that the fact that $A'B'$ is $\tfrac 12[AB+CD]$ seems to be inconsequential. It's not uncommon to include extra information in puzzles as red herrings; I tend not to like that. This is really a personal opinion, I don't know how many people share this view.

Other than these, I like the idea; I haven't used you-know-what inequality is 3-D situations before, so this feels fresh! Hope to see more of your creations. :)

Comment: Thank you and Well done! Re the $A'B'=...$ is inconsequential. I was indeed looking for a way of burying the $A'B'=C'D'$ because I was (needlessly with the benefit of hindsight) concerned otherwise it would be too obviouos. In the same way as the AM-GM owes its appearance mostly to the fact that otherwise our ptosh friend would be visually jumping out of the expressions you described as scary.

Comment: Also, I felt the ugliness of writing out $xy$ would actually add to thet satisfaction that comes with the model solution since being a bit clever allowed you to completely bypass ever having to do that in the first place.